# Verificar si existe una palabra en un txt antes de leerlo

Tags: java

estaba intentando hacer este ejercicio

> 11.Implemente un método que dado un archivo de entrada (archivo que será leído) y uno de
>   salida (archivo que será escrito), especificados con su ruta, y dos palabras:
>   palabraAReemplazar y nuevaPalabra, devuelva en el archivo de salida el contenido del
>   archivo de entrada, pero con la primer palabra reemplazada por la segunda.
>   public void reemplazar(String archivoOrigen, String archivoDestino, String
>   palabraAReemplazar, String nuevaPalabra).
>   Ejemplo:
>   Supongamos el contenido del archivo origen:
>   “Un kit también puede formar parte de otro kit, por lo que un kit es un grupo de elementos
>   de cualquiera de los tipos de elementos (simples o kit). Cada tipo de elemento tiene un
>   código, nombre y un precio.”
>   La palabra a reemplazar “kit” y la palabra nueva “set”, el método escribirá en el archivo
>   destino (archivoDestino) el contenido:
>   “Un set también puede formar parte de otro set, por lo que un set es un grupo de elementos
>   de cualquiera de los tipos de elementos (simples o set). Cada tipo de elemento tiene un
>   código, nombre y un precio.”
>   Resuelva este ejercicio utilizando un objeto StringTokenizer para su implementación.

E logrado implementar la parte de reemplazar una palabra por otra, pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es antes verificar si la palabra a reemplazar se encuentra en el archivo que sera leido, pero no logro hacerlo, este es mi codigo

```
package Ejercicio11;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RemplazarPorPalabraV2 {

FileReader frEntrada;
FileWriter fwSalida;
BufferedReader brEntrada;
String linea;

public void remplazar(String archivoOrigen, String archivoDestino, String
        palabraAReemplazar, String nuevaPalabra) throws Exception {

    try {

        frEntrada = new FileReader(archivoOrigen);
        brEntrada = new BufferedReader(frEntrada);
        fwSalida = new FileWriter(archivoDestino);
        verificarSiExistePalabraARemplazar(palabraAReemplazar);

        while ((linea = brEntrada.readLine()) != null) {


            fwSalida.write(lineaTemp.replace(palabraAReemplazar, nuevaPalabra)+"\r\n");
            fwSalida.flush();



        }

        fwSalida.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("el archivo no se encuentra en la ruta");

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();


    }

}

private void verificarSiExistePalabraARemplazar(String palabraAReemplazar) throws Exception {

    String lineaTemp;
    String pedacitos[];
    boolean noTienePalabra = true;
    FileReader frTemp = frEntrada;
    BufferedReader brTemp = new BufferedReader(frTemp);

    while ((lineaTemp = brTemp.readLine()) != null ){

        if(lineaTemp.contains(palabraAReemplazar)){
            noTienePalabra = false;


        }

    } 


    if(noTienePalabra){

        throw new Exception("La palabra a reemplazar no se encuentra en el archivo");


        }


    }

}
```

el problema es que este metodo verificar hace que deje de funcionar bien el metodo de reemplazar, directamente no me escribe nada en el fichero de salida, alguna idea?

Comment: Si.. a que te referis con verificar antes? para verificar, tenes que leerlo, por lo cual, ya podes hacer el cambio y listo. No hay forma de saberlo sin leer el archivo. Por lo tanto, no tiene sentido. Ademas, tu metodo, devuelve algo que tu metodo principal no esta mirando.

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que antes que entre al while del metodo reemplazar, se fije si la palabra a reemplazar esta en el archivo, y si no esta lanzar una excepcion

Comment: y tira la excepcion? o alguna excepcion? donde estas cerrando los archivos?

Comment: No me tira ninguna exepcion, ni tampoco me escribe nada en el archivo de destino, en el metodo verificarSiExistePalabraARemplazar cuando cierro el archivo me tira un error de Stream closed

Comment: El metodo verificar no esta cerrando el archivo, que para colmo ya estaba abierto en el metodo anterior..

Comment: Si quiero cerrar el archivo en el metodo verificar me tira un error de stream closed

Answer (score 0):

A ver.
No te cambia nada, porque no has programado nada que lo cambie.
Por otro lado, el booleano "notienepalabra" yo lo llamaría "tienepalabra" y lo inicializaría en false.
Es decir,si no encuentra la palabra, se queda en false, si alguna vez la ha encontradoo, se pone a true.

Prueba esto:

```
while ((lineaTemp = brTemp.readLine()) != null ){

    if(lineaTemp.contains(palabraAReemplazar)){
        tienePalabra = true;
        lineaTemp.replaceAll(palabraAReemplazar, nuevaPalabra) //ten en cuenta que tienes que traer la variable esta


    }

} 



if(!tienePalabra){

    throw new Exception("La palabra a reemplazar no se encuentra en el archivo");


    }


}
```

Sería algo parecido a esto. Acuérdate también de cerrar el fichero una vez lo abres. Pero tienes que usar el replaceAll, que no lo estabas haciendo.

Comment: muchas gracias, al final pude hacerlo